# CakePHP 2.0: How to switch to js layout?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I would like an action in one of my controllers to output plain javascript, but I can't find anything in the Book on the proper way to achieve this.

I've tried `$this->response->type('js');` which does set the `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8` but doesn't change the layout to Layouts/js/default.ctp

I keep finding posts all over saying to use `$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'js')`
but it's as if that method no longer exists: [What's the usage of app\views\layouts\js?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/wZu0NGguQxg)

The only thing that has worked so far is `$this->layoutPath = "js";` according to: [How to change cakephp layout?](http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-cakephp-layout/)

However, this article seems to be from Cake 1.3 days. Is this still the correct way to do switch to the js layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestHandlerComponent::renderAs` still exists:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::renderAs

Don't forget to include the Request Handler component in your controller, and then it should work fine.

```
public $components = array
(
    'RequestHandler'
);

public function action()
{
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'js');
}
```